# Gamesalad game works on iOS but doesn't work on old Android phones

Tags: 2d-games, gamesalad

The game runs perfect on iOS devices (even old ones like iPad 1) and on new Android phone (Nexus 4) but it just crash from beginning on Nexus S with 2.3.4 OS version. Just showing the splash screen and after few seconds black screen then go back to previous screen (the point left when launching the game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a 0.5 MB static image that was loaded on start. Reducing the size of the image to less than 100kB solves the issue. All my graphic elements loaded are less than 1 MB, it is weird that Nexus S could handle just such a small amount using Gamesalad.

I learned that any change on graphic loading element should be tested at least on the oldest device I can get.